# Empty file fields

Tags: jquery, file, css-selectors

i must check all :file fields, all fields must be not empty. i use code

`function CheckFiles() {
    var t = $('.uploadElement:empty').size();
    alert(t);
}`

but t return all uploadElement elements count. how to get empty :file fields?

sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

this should return all empty file inputs

```
$('input:file[value=""]')
```

or

```
$(':[value=""].uploadElement')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? if so please select it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.uploadElement:file').is(":empty");
```

Comment: `:empty` means it has no child elements, which is always true :)